# use direnv then the gopls error said can't import fmt

Tags: go, vim, direnv

I started using `direnv` recently.

I created a `.envrc` file in my project’s root directory.

There is only one line in `.envrc`:

```
export GOPATH=$(pwd)
```

I use vim with coc & gopls to write go, but when I open `main.go` coc shows this error

```
Error [compiler] could not import os (no package for import os)
```

This is my project structure

```
.
├── .envrc
├── bin -> /root/go/bin
├── out
├── pkg -> /root/go/pkg
└── src
    ├── github.com -> /root/go/src/github.com
    ├── golang.org -> /root/go/src/golang.org
    └── monkey
        ├── lexer
        │   ├── lexer.go
        │   └── lexer_test.go
        ├── main.go
        ├── out
        ├── repl
        │   └── repl.go
        └── token
            └── token.go
```

Comment: Please add the output of  `$ env` to your question [by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59441573/edit).

Comment: I have to admit it looks a little strange that those paths link to `/root`—you’re not developing code logged in as the root user are you?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg or `printenv GOPATH` would surely be enough? Maybe `env | grep 'GO.*'

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Either would do, ofc. Trying to keep it simple for OP, and people to answer know what to look for, anyway.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble i was logged in as root

Comment: @happycoding ahhh! Why? (That’s a Bad Idea™️)